# Can I have an optional parameter in dataclasses that is omitted when transformed to dict?

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses, pyright

I wish to perform static type checking (`pylance` in `vscode`) on some dictionaries. The "tricky" part is the I want some of the parameters to be optional and not show up at all in the dictionary. I've tried using `dataclasses` and `TypedDict` but without luck so far.

```py
from typing import Optional, List
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict


@dataclass
class SubOrder:
    name: str


@dataclass
class Order:
    name: str
    sub_orders: Optional[List[SubOrder]]


assert asdict(Order(name="Pizza")) == {"name": "Pizza"}
assert asdict(Order(name="Pizza", sub_orders=[SubOrder(name="Pasta")])) == {
    "name": "Pizza",
    "sub_orders": [{"name": "Pasta"}],
}
```

Is that achievable with `dataclasses`? I basically just want my static type checker (`pylance` / `pyright`) to check my dictionaries which is why I'm using `dataclasses`. I've tried with `TypedDict` as well but the type checkers does not seem to behave like I was. They always require me to set `sub_orders`.

The following code passes but `pylance` is not happy about not having `sub_orders`.

```py
from typing import Optional, List, TypedDict


class SubOrder(TypedDict):
    name: str


class Order(TypedDict):
    name: str
    sub_orders: Optional[List[SubOrder]]


assert Order(name="Pizza") == {"name": "Pizza"}
assert Order(name="Pizza", sub_orders=[SubOrder(name="Pasta")]) == {
    "name": "Pizza",
    "sub_orders": [{"name": "Pasta"}],
}
```

#### EDIT

I've added a [bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/84) in `pylance` since this might actually be a bug in `pylance` / `pyright`

Comment: It seems like it might be better to give `sub_orders` a `default_factory` set to `list`, instead of marking it `Optional`.

Comment: `Optional[Whatever]` doesn't mean optional. It means `Union[Whatever, None]`.

Comment: But then I'd get a different dictionary. I need the `sub_orders` to not be part of the dictionary at all.

Answer (score 11):

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass
from typing import List, Optional

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class SubOrder(ValidatedDC):
    name: str


@dataclass
class Order(ValidatedDC):
    name: str
    sub_orders: Optional[List[SubOrder]] = None

    def as_dict(self):
        data = asdict(self)
        return {key: value for key, value in data.items() if value is not None}


data = {'name': 'pizza'}
order = Order(**data)
assert order.get_errors() is None
assert asdict(order) == {'name': 'pizza', 'sub_orders': None}
assert order.as_dict() == {'name': 'pizza'}

data = {'name': 'pizza', 'sub_orders': [{'name': 'pasta'}]}
order = Order(**data)
assert order.get_errors() is None
assert asdict(order) == {'name': 'pizza', 'sub_orders': [{'name': 'pasta'}]}
assert isinstance(order.sub_orders[0], SubOrder)
```

ValidatedDC - https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc

Comment: Thanks I should’ve mentioned that preferably without any third party libraries - or at least only well established ones. Sorry but thanks anyways!

Comment: You only need one file: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc/blob/master/validated_dc.py

Answer (score 10):

You can have an optional parameter in data class by setting a default value, for example an empty string `""` or `None`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typings import Optional


@dataclass
class SubOrder:
    n: Optional[int] = None
    name: str = ""
```

Comment: Is there a reason why this should be a str specifically? Would it be valid to use None for generic non-str parameters?

Comment: of course it can be.

Comment: it ought to match the type you specify